# Weeks Manifold - the Heegaard splitting and presentations of its fundamental group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, group-presentation, low-dimensional-topology

I'm working on the Heegaard splitting of some 3-manifold and I'm currently stucked on the Weeks manifold. It is a closed orientable hyperbolic 3-manifold with the smallest volume, obtained by (5, 2) and (5, 1) Dehn surgeries on the Whitehead link.

I found a presentation of the fundamental group of the Weeks manifold, it is $$\pi_1(M_W)=\langle a,b\mid a^2b^2a^2b^{-1}ab^{-1}=1,a^2b^2a^{-1}ba^{-1}b^2=1\rangle.$$

What is the rank of this group? Do you know any better presentation of the Weeks manifold's fundamental group? Or do you know the better ways to compute the Heegard genus of this manifold?

Comment: Think of Weeks manifold as (5,5/2) surgery on Whitehead link. That might be a better way to start and now we can use your favorite Kirby calculus argument to find various properties.

Answer (score 2):

Rank of this group is clearly $2$: If it were of rank $\le 1$, the group would be cyclic (finite or infinite), which cannot be the fundamental group of a hyperbolic manifold (complete, finite volume). In general, SnapPea can find Heegaard diagrams for you: https://t3m.math.uic.edu/. The Weeks manifold has genus 2, see for instance

*Vesnin, A. Yu.; Mednykh, A. D.*, [**The Heegaard genus of hyperbolic 3-manifolds of small volume**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02110720), Sib. Math. J. 37, No. 5, 893-897 (1996); translation from Sib. Mat. Zh. 37, No. 5, 1013-1018 (1996). [ZBL0887.57021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0887.57021).